# AutoMapper: Pass a parameter to destination contructor when using .ProjectTo

Tags: c#, automapper

My destination object has a one parameter contructor that I need to pass an object to it for internal use.
How do i pass this to the ProjectTo

-mapping

```
CreateMap<SomeEntity, SomeModel>();
```

-projecting

```
var param = new SomeContructorParam();
await context.SomeEntities                    
                .ProjectTo<SomeModel>() --  PASS PARAM here? how so
                .ToListAsync();
```

-dest object

```
public class SomeModel
{
    private readonly SomeContructorParam ctorParam;
    public SomeModel(SomeContructorParam ctorParam)
    {
        this.ctorParam = ctorParam;
    }
    ...

}
public class SomeContructorParam
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#parameterization

Comment: This for DI or do you just need to pass in a parameter.

Comment: I had looked through that but couldnt figure out how to pass it to the contructor, those examples assume i am assigning a public property of the destination, in my case see the OP for updated dest model code

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Construction.html

Comment: @TheGeneral the last link assumes my  contructor param is coming from the source object, or am I reading that doc wrong?  The param passed to the dest does not come from source, it is coming from outside as you see in the example given (modified the original code)

Comment: I might be doing a terrible job at explaining my delima.
SomeModel has a whole bunch of properties that match SomeEntity.  So when mapping, I want all those properties to map.  At the same time, I want to pass a parameter to my constructor of SomeModel that really has nothing to do with mapping. I simply store whats passed in the ONE param constructor to be used later on by SomeModel objects.

All documentation I have seen so far seem to do with wanting me to map the passed param to some internal property.  Maybe I am not reading things right if thats not the case

Comment: @TheGeneral  In my example code, SomeConstructorParam is private and readonly and I only want this to be "mapped" via contructor, where as all other properties to be mapped by automapper (however it does it)

Comment: Test it, but apparently this particular case doesn't work.  See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2745).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu If i understand your suggestion correctly on that other reply posted.  That would possibly work if i create a property on the dest object and when .MapFrom is called it would possible work.

My need is specifically to pass the needed ctor param at .ProjectTo level and not the map configuration which seems to be the suggested way.

Give the example above, how would the suggested solution look?

Comment: Actually I think the easiest way would be to use ConstructUsing with the parameter you pass.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu ContructUsing assumes I am passing something from the source object and must be setup during initialization.  Param I want to pass does not come from source and is not known during initialization (asp.net core startup.cs).

Comment: No. I think you should read the docs.

Comment: @Lucian which parts of the docs? There doesn't seem to be any documention regarding passing runtime params into a constructor when using ProjectTo

Comment: Because it's the same as all the other cases when you use ConstructUsing.

Answer (score 4):

Tried and tested.

**Mapping:**

```
SomeContructorParam emptyParm = null
CreateMap<SomeEntity, SomeModel>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => new SomeModel(emptyParm));
```

**Projecting**

```
var param = new SomeContructorParam();
await context.SomeEntities                    
            .ProjectTo<SomeModel>(new { emptyParm = param })
            .ToListAsync();
```

[UPDATE 05/02/2023]
This works in version 8.x as this was the latest version at time of writing.

The below works with v9.x-12.x

**Projecting**

```
var param = new SomeContructorParam();
await context.SomeEntities                    
            .ProjectTo<SomeModel>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider, new { emptyParm = param })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I don't understand. What version of AutoMapper is this? Can somebody extend this answer with context?

Comment: Where in the Profile/Mapping is reading the value of the param?

Comment: This works for version 8.x I'll have a look at what works with the latest 12.0.1 and update my answer if I find out how it's done

Comment: Edited for v9+.  @zoinky perhaps you could accept my answer unless you have any more comments/questions??!